# Binary classifier on imbalanced dataset yields weird PR curve

Tags: naive-bayes-classifier, metric, smote, imbalanced-learn

I have a dataset with ~6M points, 9 features and two classes. The minority class represents just under 2% of the data. The data is first divided into 100 batches and a different classifier is trained for each batch using the rest of the data.

So far I have tried using sklearn's Naive Bayes classifier trained first using all the data, then downsampling, and then SMOTE. Every time I get this weird shape on the PR curve. I am now trying with random forest, but I am not confident. Does this suggest that the features design is bad? Any suggestions on what would be my next step?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m concerned that in the PCA visual both classes are stacked right on top of each other. Since your input features are only 9, I suggest running some box plots by class to see if there is any differences between the univariate distributions.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but since I didn't design the features and only recalculated them on data I obtained from an other lab I wanted to try to reproduce what they did. I don't have access to PR or ROC curve or any other metric beyond accuracy.

Comment: It looks like the features all look alike between the two classes. Depending how the data is obtained, sampled, or generated there may be more informative features to consider. Also, when you build your ML model, are you scaling and standardizing the data?

Comment: The data is from expensive mass spectrometry experiments and domain experts tell me that those features should be the most informative. Although I agree with you that the boxplots say otherwise. The preprocessing involves only binning in 1000 equally sized bins. Should I try normalizing in some way?

Comment: Yes, try normalizing your data

Comment: normalizing gives essentially the same results... @Jon If you want to answer with your suggestion of more informative features I will accept it as the answer for the post. Thank you!